# What to put as the Provider for a mocked IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, pex-and-moles, moles

I am working with [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/default.aspx) and mocking a System.Data.Linq.Table.

I got it constructing fine, but when I use it, it wants IQueryable.**Provider** to be mocked (moled) as well.

I just want it to use normal Linq To Objects.  Any idea what that would be?

Here is the syntax I can use:

```
MTable<User> userTable = new System.Data.Linq.Moles.MTable<User>();
userTable.Bind(new List<User> { UserObjectHelper.TestUser() });

// this is the line that needs help
MolesDelegates.Func<IQueryProvider> provider = //Insert provider here!
                                                             ^
userTable.ProviderSystemLinqIQueryableget = provider         |
                                                             |
                                                             | 
what can I put here? ----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest would be a `List<T>` which can be used as `IQueryable<T>` via `.AsQueryable()`.

```
MolesDelegates.Func<IQueryProvider> provider = () => userLinqList.AsQueryable().Provider;
```

That's what I use as a in memory database to mock out Linq2Sql. Simple and elegant.

Comment: `MolesDelegates.Func<IQueryProvider> provider = new List<User>();` says that List<T> does not convert to MolesDelegates.Func<IQueryProvider>

Comment: `MolesDelegates.Func<IQueryProvider> provider = new List<User>().AsQueryable().Provider`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The syntax turned out to be: `MolesDelegates.Func<IQueryProvider> provider = () => userLinqList.AsQueryable().Provider;`

Comment: yeah, glad you could figure it out. I am on the road atm and SO is terrible on iPhone :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to bind the list.AsQueryable() to the table. The IQueryable methods would automatically be rerouted to the list.